# Как получить значение из TextField и вывести его в Label в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Создал интерфейс через javafx scene builder, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки происходило получение значения из TextField и затем это значение в Label? Пробую через id.getText(); но значение даже через System.out.println(); не выводится - открывается консоль и все.

Comment: код предоставьте пожалуйста.

Comment: если без кода то так: `label.setText(textField.getText())`. При этом `label` и `textField` должны быть объявлены как поля в контроллере с аннотацией `@FXML` и в самом xml, у соответствующих элементах, задан `id` такой же как и название поля в контроллере.

Comment: Нужно ещё в SceneBuilder прописать событие для кнопки onAction, по которому создать метод-обработчик в коде.